# JavaScript: Deep Copy Circular JSON

Tags: javascript, json, clone, deep-copy

### intro:

I'm trying to write a deep copy method, but need to keep track of my visited nodes, so that I can link to the previously `visitedNode` instead of deep copying forever until stack overflow.

### attempts:

```
var visitedNodes = {};
var obj = {}; obj.a = obj;   // circular; can't use JSON.stringify)
var obj2 = {};

visitedNodes[obj] = "should need key obj (not obj2) to access this string";

console.log(visitedNodes[obj2]);    // logs the string unfortunately
```

I don't have a unique way of storing the memory location -- it stores itself at `[object Object]` and I can't use JSON.stringify because it's a circular structure

---

I tried using `var visitedNodes = new Map();` but still no dice

---

My current approach is to utilize the `Array.prototype.indexOf` function, but I don't know if it works with circular structures either, because I'm getting a stack overflow here too!!!

```
this.clone = function (item, visitedNodes) {
    visitedNodes = visitedNodes || [];
    if (typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item)) {
        if (visitedNodes.indexOf(item) === -1) {
            var cloneObject = {};
            visitedNodes.push(cloneObject);
            for (var i in item) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    cloneObject[i] = this.clone(item[i], visitedNodes);
                }
            }
            return cloneObject;
        } else {
            return visitedNodes[visitedNodes.indexOf(item)];
        }
    }
    else if (typeof item === "object" && Array.isArray(item)) {
        if (visitedNodes.indexOf(item) === -1) {
            var cloneArray = [];
            visitedNodes.push(cloneArray);
            for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
                cloneArray.push(this.clone(item[j], visitedNodes));
            }
            return cloneArray;
        } else {
            return visitedNodes[visitedNodes.indexOf(item)];
        }
    }

    return item; // not object, not array, therefore primitive
};
```

---

### the question:

Anyone have any ideas for getting a unique memory address so I can determine if I've been to the Object's reference before? I believe I could construct a unique hash based off `Object.keys()` and `Object.prototype.constructor` but that seems absurd and will give false positives if constructor is the same and the child keys are the same as the parent

Comment: Look at Douglas Crockford's JSON.decycle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075308/avoiding-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json/24075430#24075430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visitedNodes save the original reference, and create another array to save with same index the clone object to use when is a reference.

```
function deepClone(obj) {
    var visitedNodes = [];
    var clonedCopy = [];
    function clone(item) {
        if (typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item)) {
            if (visitedNodes.indexOf(item) === -1) {
                visitedNodes.push(item);
                var cloneObject = {};
                clonedCopy.push(cloneObject);
                for (var i in item) {
                    if (item.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        cloneObject[i] = clone(item[i]);
                    }
                }
                return cloneObject;
            } else {
                return clonedCopy[visitedNodes.indexOf(item)];
            }
        }
        else if (typeof item === "object" && Array.isArray(item)) {
            if (visitedNodes.indexOf(item) === -1) {
                var cloneArray = [];
                visitedNodes.push(item);
                clonedCopy.push(cloneArray);
                for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
                    cloneArray.push(clone(item[j]));
                }
                return cloneArray;
            } else {
                return clonedCopy[visitedNodes.indexOf(item)];
            }
        }

        return item; // not object, not array, therefore primitive
    }
    return clone(obj);
}

var obj = {b: 'hello'};
obj.a = { c: obj };
var dolly = deepClone(obj);
obj.d = 'hello2';
console.log(obj);
console.log(dolly);
```

the code running example:
http://jsbin.com/favekexiba/1/watch?js,console

Comment: i believe i'm doing the same thing, just using a short circuit operator to keep passing the visitedNodes reference recursively instead of using a helper function

Comment: and this should work, i think the main issue has to do with our specific JS core

Comment: no we aren't doing the same... you code is almost there but...  `({} === {}) === false` the objects they have the same properties, but 2 different objects

Comment: instead of this: `visitedNodes.push(cloneObject);` you should do this: `visitedNodes.push(item);`

Comment: the only step left is determining `function.bind(visitedNode)` context

Answer (score 1):

The code in the answer of Fetz works great but breaks on Date objects. Here is a patched version:

```
const visitedNodes = [];
const clonedCopy = [];

function clone(item) {
  if (typeof item === 'object') {
    if (item instanceof Date) { // Date
      if (visitedNodes.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        visitedNodes.push(item);
        var cloneObject = new Date(item);
        clonedCopy.push(cloneObject);
        return cloneObject;
      }
      return clonedCopy[visitedNodes.indexOf(item)];
    } else if (XMLDocument && item instanceof XMLDocument) { // XML Document
      if (visitedNodes.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        visitedNodes.push(item);
        const cloneObject = item.implementation.createDocument(item.documentElement.namespaceURI, null, null);
        const newNode = cloneObject.importNode(item.documentElement, true);
        cloneObject.appendChild(newNode);
        clonedCopy.push(cloneObject);
        return cloneObject;
      }
      return clonedCopy[visitedNodes.indexOf(item)];
    } else if (!Array.isArray(item)) { // Object
      if (visitedNodes.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        visitedNodes.push(item);
        var cloneObject = {};
        clonedCopy.push(cloneObject);
        for (const i in item) {
          if (item.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            cloneObject[i] = clone(item[i]);
          }
        }
        return cloneObject;
      }
      return clonedCopy[visitedNodes.indexOf(item)];
    } else if (Array.isArray(item)) { // Array
      if (visitedNodes.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        const cloneArray = [];
        visitedNodes.push(item);
        clonedCopy.push(cloneArray);
        for (let j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
          cloneArray.push(clone(item[j]));
        }
        return cloneArray;
      }
      return clonedCopy[visitedNodes.indexOf(item)];
    }
  }

  return item; // not date, not object, not array, therefore primitive
}
return clone(obj);
```

I would've preferred to edit the answer of Fetz but the edit queue is full.

**edit 19/07/2017**: Added XML Document cloning as well